# New-ish r user: How do I write predictions to a file using r?

Tags: r

I've identified key variables, I've trained a multiple regression model based on the variables, I've brought in a file that holds all the necessary variables (it's the full universe though (~290k vs 2.2k that the model was built on)), I've successfully generated a prediction based on the model. Now I just want to write the predictions to either the big file or to a separate file that I can then merge with the big file.

Here's the script I used to generate the predictions:

```
predict(fit1, Modeled, se.fit = FALSE, scale = NULL, df = Inf,
    interval = c("none", "confidence", "prediction"),
    level = 0.95, type = c("response", "terms"),
    terms = NULL, na.action = na.pass,
    pred.var = res.var/weights, weights = 1)
```

I've tried cbind and a variety of other things I found while Googling around but can't get any of them to work. Would someone mind helping out?

Update:
Here's the save command that I last tried to use.

```
save(fit1, list = character(),
     file = stop(fit1),
     ascii = FALSE, version = NULL, envir = parent.frame(),
     eval.promises = TRUE, precheck = TRUE)
```

It generated the following error.

```
Error in save(fit1, list = character(), file = stop(fit1), ascii = FALSE,  :
```

Which was followed by a short list of some of the predictions.

Update:
Ran this script:

```
save(fit1, list = character(),
     file = "fit1",
     ascii = FALSE, version = NULL, envir = parent.frame(),
     eval.promises = TRUE, precheck = TRUE)

save.image(file = ".RData", version = NULL, ascii = FALSE,
           compress = !ascii, safe = TRUE)
```

Which returned this error:

```
Error in save(list = names(.GlobalEnv), file = outfile, version = version,  : 
  object 'ascii' not found
Warning in file.remove(outfile) :
  cannot remove file '.RDataTmp', reason 'No such file or directory'
```

I'm pretty sure that the first error is the real issue here because the second command won't run successfully without the first command having worked.

Comment: can you include code of what you've tried?

Comment: I guess you want `save`?

Comment: Sure, here's the save code I most recently tried. 

save(fit1, list = character(),
     file = stop(fit1),
     ascii = FALSE, version = NULL, envir = parent.frame(),
     eval.promises = TRUE, precheck = TRUE)

It generated the following error:
Error in save(fit1, list = character(), file = stop(fit1), ascii = FALSE,  : 
Followed by a list of some of the predictions.

Comment: Okay well that looks like a mess, let me dump that up top.

Comment: Why are you producing a stop error for the file name?  `file = stop(fit1)` is not right.  Just use a character string denoting the file name.

Comment: Was trying to replicate this within my environment. 
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/save.html

Comment: I agree, they shouldn't have used a stop message in the default argument list for `save()`.  It's confusing.  If you want the file to be named `fit1` then use `file = "fit1"`

Comment: Awesome thanks, I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Threw an error on the ascii segment. Updated above. Thanks for the help you've given so far I really appreciate it.

Comment: Final update, figured it all out. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

A minimal reproducible example would help in answering the question.  Also, you said you wanted to save the predictions, however your `save` command is being passed the `fit1` `lm` object, and not the output of predict. I assume `fit1` is an `lm` object because it is the first argument you are passing to `predict`.

However assuming you want to save the vector output of `predict` you can simply write it to a csv file.

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
fit1 <- lm(x ~ y)
write.csv(predict(fit1), file = "predictions.csv")
```

EDIT: Assuming from your comment you want the predictions combined with the "big file".

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
fit1 <- lm(x ~ y)
Modeled <- matrix(rnorm(1000), nrow = 100, ncol = 10)
output <- cbind(predict(fit1), Modeled)
write.csv(output, file = "predictions.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: First, Matt, thanks for taking a look at my question. I just tried your suggestion and the file it produces is the scores for ~2300 records not the big file.

Comment: The big file being the one named "Modeled" above.

Comment: Your question said you "want to write the predictions to either the big file or to a separate file".  I don't know what 'write the predictions to ... the big file' means. Maybe you mean combine the predictions with the big file and write the resulting matrix/dataframe?  I originally just output the predictions as a separate file.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity, it's my first day on the site so I'm kind of getting used to things around here. The real underlying goal here is to take the predictions that were generated by the model and apply them to the file named "Modeled". If the best way to do that is to create a new dataframe under a new name then I'm okay with that I just need to apply those scores to that file.